# Why is inf and sup of null sets defined as infinities

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I'm reading the definition of $inf\emptyset$ and $sup\emptyset$.

a) I'm wondering why $inf\emptyset = \infty$ and $sup\emptyset = -\infty$. I would have expected both to be undefined.

b) In general, can something equal infinity if it's not in the extend real number system? Should I assume they are using about extended real numbers in these definitions?

Comment: As a general rule, if we can get away with defining an expression (i.e. chosen rules for how those kinds of expressions will still remain valid) then we do define them. So for instance in combinatorics and elementary set theory we can justify $0!=1$ and $0^0=1$.

Comment: If you're not using the extended real number system, what are $\inf \mathbb R$ and $\sup \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume that the author used the extended real number line for these definitions.

In fact, here's a motivation for above definition.

If you have two sets $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb R$, then you want them to satisfy
$$\inf A\geq \inf B,\quad \sup A\leq \sup B.$$

You can check that this always works whenever both $A$ and $B$ are non-empty.

We want this to remain true even if we accept $A=\varnothing$. We then must have
$$\inf\varnothing\geq \inf B,\quad \sup\varnothing\leq \sup B$$
for *any* set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Since you can then choose $B=\{x\}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ arbitrarily large (or small), we are forced to define
$$\inf\varnothing=+\infty,\quad \sup\varnothing=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 8):

Having$$\inf\emptyset=\infty\text{ and }\sup\emptyset=-\infty\tag1$$is that only way of defining $\inf\emptyset$ and $\sup\emptyset$ so that you always have$$A\subset B\implies \inf A\geqslant\inf B\quad\text{and}\quad\sup A\leqslant\sup B.$$And, yes, you can only have $(1)$ if we are working with the extended real numbers.

Comment: Just a small question: when you write $A\subset B$ do you allow the possibility that $A=B$? And if so, is there a reason you prefer writing this over writing $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Is, I do allow that. I do it because, like most mathematicians, I read “$A\subset B$” as “$A$ is a subset of $B$”. And so I never use the notation $A\subseteq B$ (although I sometimes use $A\varsubsetneq B$).

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, this assumes that we are working in the extended reals.

Contrary to what the others said, though, $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$ is not a definition made out of convenience. It is a direct consequence of the normal definition of the supremum: the smallest upper bound of the set. Since everything is an upper bound of the empty set (everything is larger than all its elements), the smallest upper bound is $-\infty$.

Essentially the same applies to the infimum.

Answer (score 1):

You should assume the presence of the "extended real number system" when thinking about the infimum (about the supremum) of a set $M \subset \mathbb{R}$.

You should do this because it is helpful. I visualize it dynamically and non-rigorously, as follows. The extended real number system is a train track or subway line with a western terminus at $-\infty$ and an eastern terminus at $+\infty$.

While traveling from the western to the eastern end, each real number is passed.

Now the algorithm for $\inf$ is as follows. Let the train begin at $-\infty$, and for a fixed set $M$ let a flag be placed at each real $a \in M$.

When the train encounters or hits the first flag, it halts and declares its output as the real corresponding to that first flag. (*Why is this not rigorously correct? Consider $\{a \in \mathbb{R}: 0<a<1\}$.*)

But, in the case $M=\emptyset,$ the eastbound train never encounters a flag, and proceeds to the end of the line, which is $+\infty$.

The case for $\sup$ is similar but the train is westbound departing from $+\infty.$

Comment: I should mention also the case where $M$ is unbounded on the left (west). In this case I visualize that the train is unable to depart from the western terminus, for the case of the algorithm for $\inf$. Thus $\inf M = -\infty.$